# Is it a good practice to use recursion to reload an ad using Admob if it fails when it is loaded?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, ads

I'm using this code to load and show an interstitial ad. It works fine but as you can see if the ad fails to load `onAdFailedToLoad`, the interstitial ad is recursively requested. Maybe this could be a really bad practice as if the ad is not loaded, the function could be called a huge number of times. But, I have thought that as I'm requesting the ad after the device is connected to the internet, the probability that the ad is loaded should be almost 100%, but I was just wondering if it is a bad practice to do this. The interstitial ad is shown in the 2 activities, as you can see in one of them, it is shown when a button is clicked and after it is clicked there is an intent to move to another activity. The other activity that the interstitial is shown is almost the same, in this second activity it is shown when the game is paused and also when the level is finished. I don´t know if it is important but all the levels are in the same activity, so the interstitial as I have said is only shown in 2 different activities.

```java
 @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
            CallNewInertial();
        }


   private void CallNewInertial() {
        ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(Activityone.this);
        if (cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            requestNewInterstitial();
        }
    }


 private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        InterstitialAd.load(Activityone.this, getString(R.string.interid),
                adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                        requestNewInterstitial();
                    }
                });
    }




  btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            
                if (mInterstitialAd != null) {

                    mInterstitialAd.show(Activityone.this);

                    mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                  
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {

                        }

                    });
```

fixed code to make it perfect:

```java
 @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        requestNewInterstitial(5);

        }




 private void requestNewInterstitial(int maxRetry) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        InterstitialAd.load(Activityone.this, getString(R.string.interid),
                adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                     if (maxRetry>0){
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                        requestNewInterstitial(maxRetry-1);
                     }
                    }
                });
    }




  btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            
                if (mInterstitialAd != null) {

                    mInterstitialAd.show(Activityone.this);

                    mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                  
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {

                        }

                    });
```

(using delay),updated code to make it even more perfect:

```java
 @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        requestNewInterstitial(5);

        }




 private void requestNewInterstitial(int maxRetry) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        InterstitialAd.load(Activityone.this, getString(R.string.interid),
                adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {


          if (maxRetry>0){
                         new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                  public void run() {
                 mInterstitialAd = null;
                 requestNewInterstitial(maxRetry-1);
               }
              //delay of 10 seconds
              }, 10000);
                   
                    }
                });
                     }
           
    }




  btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            
                if (mInterstitialAd != null) {

                    mInterstitialAd.show(Activityone.this);

                    mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                  
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {

                        }

                    });
```

Comment: I wouldn't call that exactly recursion, being event driven. Still, I'd say it's not a good practice to use recursion for something like that.
Every time you call a recursive function, you fill a bigger part of the stack and, without a secure exit strategy, it can lead to memory overflow or stack overflow.
In this case it should be ok, because the function fails and it should free the stack, because it's an event that tries reloading. But I'm not certain. It depends on how events works internally.

Comment: @LucaScarcia so in this case, is it okay to reload the ad when it fails to load as I have made as when the ad fails to load this call of the function is freed from the stack?

Comment: (sorry if I mispelled), an application has one fixed requirement: it must terminate at some point. So, the best practice would be terminating the application if the download fails after a fixed number of retries (i.e. 5 retries). Still, if you are sure that you're not cluttering the stack, then yes, do it (I suppose it's critical for your application to download that data). Still, it would be better to close the application after 5 failed downloads (because there can be network problems or something like that).

Comment: @LucaScarcia So is it a good practice to reload the ad a fixed number of times in the onAdFailedToLoad? I mean, is that function necessary if I am checking if the device is connected to the internet before? Or I shouldn´t check if the decice is connected to the internet and reload the ad a fixed number in onAdFailedToLoad()?. Or maybe the best option is using both (as I have done but reloading the ad a fixed number of times only). Sorry for the confusion

Comment: if you can check if the device is connected beforehand it's obviously better, (if the procedure has no timeout). Trying to download data has a long timeout (it can be 30 seconds or even more). Depending on the application, you can just go for a different ad instead of reloading. Still, if you need to retry loading that ad, it's best practice to set a finite number of retries (5 is the norm, but would still be 2 minutes and half to wait in timeouts),

Comment: @LucaScarcia well, but if I set the finite number of reloads to 5, is it really necesary to check the internet connection before the ad is loaded or is it okay to just load the ad as it will be only reloaded maximum 5 times?

Comment: It's not needed and usually it's not even done. This kind of operations happen in background and systems are smart enough to make download fail immediately if the connection is not available. Usually but not always. Best practice is avoiding infinite loops while trying to download a resource that is not available. All the rest is your design choice.

Comment: @LucaScarcia okay, so I have edited the code adding the maximum fixed number of reloads and I have also deleted the function that checked for the internet connection. Do you think now it is perfect like that?

Comment: Not sure it will work as intended. I would have used `private void requestNewInterstitial(int maxRetry) {` and then call in the fail handler `if(maxRetry>0) requestNewInterstitial(maxRetry-1);`

Comment: @LucaScarcia I have reedited it. The solution you told me remembers me to eliminate the tail recursion to optimize the code, did you make it like that to avoid tail recursion? Check it now how I changed it, is it now perfect and do you think will work as intended now? Thanks

Comment: I did that thinking about a concurrent scenario, where multiple call to the function can be done by different processes. Don't know what will happen t oa static local varialbe in those scenarios. Let's avoid it. Also, you are missing `requestNewInterstitial(max-1);`. You forgot the parameter. Also, don't use decrement while calling recursively. If you use max-- instead of --max, it will become an infinite loop.

Comment: @LucaScarcia yes, no need of decrement I made a mistake. I have reedited it, is that looking perfect now?

Comment: Don't call it perfect, because perfection doesn't exist ;) But, yes, it works.

Comment: @LucaScarcia I have thought of adding a delay before requesting new add. Do you think it is a good idea to make it a little more perfect? I have thought of using  Looper.getMainLooper(). I am updating the code with the delay implementation to let you check if it is looking okay because actually I I'm doubting whether it's okay as I've done or not.

Comment: @Eldestonmillador sorry, didn't connect for a few day. I don't understand the need for that 10 seconds delay. A fail to download is already a 30 seconds delay. Never saw anybody call a delay before retrying to download the resource. I mean... I see the logic behind it, but usually you want it to fail as fast as possible to manage the inability to retreave the data, that's why you don't add delays. 5 retries + the first try is alread 3 minutes of waiting. I don't see a reason to add 50 more seconds.